# How can I set default value of StringVar() as null in tkinter module of Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to set default value of StringVar() as null. I am using Tkinter module of Python. I have already tried the following code:

```
mothers_name_var = StringVar()
mothers_name_entrybox = Entry(add, width=50, text=mothers_name_var)
mothers_name_var.set(None)
mothers_name_entrybox.place(x=250, y=150)
```

What can I try in order to achieve this?

Comment: There is no null, but `mothers_name_var.set('')` should be fine to use.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, an instance of `StringVar` cannot hold a null value. It can only hold strings. The default value is an empty string, which is the closest value to `None` that you can get.

The reason is that `StringVar` is just a wrapper around a variable that exists inside an embedded Tcl interpreter. Tcl knows nothing about python `None` values. In order to be passed into and back out of the Tcl interpreter, it must be a string.